Meta analysis with overidentified 2SLS estimates
To meta analyze estimates of some parameter $\theta$, we assume we have estimates $\hat{\theta_i} = \theta_i + \epsilon_i$, where $\theta_i \sim G(\theta)$ and $\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma_i^2)$. If these estimates are from RCTs, we may be happy with these assumptions. But if these estimates are from non experimental studies, we may not believe  that $E[\epsilon_i] = 0$ since some studies are biased.
Obviously in the most general setting this problem is intractable. But what if our $\hat{\theta_i}$ are 2-stage least squares estimates, and we have many instruments $Z_i$ for each regression $i$? Then we have overidentification tests for the validity of each instrument set, yielding J-statistics in each individual 2SLS regression. Could we use these overidentification tests to weight each $\hat{\theta_i}$, giving more weight to estimates with $\hat{\theta_i}$ from studies with lower J-statistics (i.e. instruments with more validity)? Would that be an improvement over simply aggregating them with inverse variance weights, as in classical meta-analysis?
This is a specific example of a more general question about aggregating estimates of possibly-misspecified models. Another example might be meta-analyzing maximum likelihood estimates, using the likelihood function in each study as weights on each estimate.
